# Responding to DMCA takedowns

Tags: discussion, dmca-notice

Currently the github repo https://github.com/wearejust/laravel-amp is unavailable due to a DMCA [takedown notice](https://github.com/github/dmca/commit/24873553bcf9b72cf217695ef9022598cc9b7934).

The copyright claim is for code posted as an [answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707938/google-amp-with-laravel)

Even ignoring the general terrible nature of the DMCA, this appears to be a bogus takedown notice as the code covered is not big enough to be copyrightable.

Additionally, the person submitting the DMCA takedown notice has lied:

> Is the work licensed under an open source license? If so, which open source license? Are the allegedly infringing files being used under the open source license, or are they in violation of the license?
>
> It is not licensed under open source license and it is a way to use in people's own projects not making it a package for public use.

That is false, as code submitted to Stack Overflow is licensed under a [Creative Commons](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) license.

Is this something that should be brought to Stack Overflow's attention, or is it drama that the site doesn't want to get involved with?

Direct link to the DMCA [takedown notice here](https://github.com/github/dmca/blob/master/2020/05/2020-05-21-AMP.md).

Comment: There is nothing for Stack Overflow to do unless the DMCA is filed against content on Stack Overflow. It is up to the author of the repo to file a [counter notice](https://help.github.com/en/github/site-policy/guide-to-submitting-a-dmca-counter-notice). That said, I am not a lawyer, so you know, find a lawyer. Also, that link says the process takes 10-14 days before the content is reenabled.

Comment: *"... code submitted to Stack Overflow is licensed under a Creative Commons license."* - Yes which means that the work built upon the code has to be covered under the same license and provide attribution and a link to the license. (Not that we can check the license or how the code is used on GH because it's been taken down)

Comment: How I suspect these DMCA fraudsters work is to scrape websites to find "copied" texts, file a takedown notice and send both involved  owners an invoice. One invoice is for resolving the takedown notice, the other is a finders fee ...

Comment: "The copyright claim is for code posted as an answer" actually, for code posted as question. The link isn't a link to an answer, but a question.

Comment: @Nick according to meta information, the repository is under MIT. (you can check the user repositories in their profile)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I can't see if the person who filed the complaint is the same person who answered the question. If they are the same person, then it would be reasonable for SO to stop them posting any more answers imo, if they aren't going to abide by stackoverflows terms and conditions.

Comment: @Danack: Is this your repository? Or are you in any way authorized by the repository owner to get in contact with SO? The first step step in any way is to file a [counter notice](https://help.github.com/en/github/site-policy/guide-to-submitting-a-dmca-counter-notice), but this may only be done by the owner of the repo or someone authorized by the owner. I'm not sure how SO (or anyone on meta) would be able to help with that.

Comment: Some possible forks of the repo that you can look at: https://github.com/masnatacion/laravel-amp/network/members https://github.com/fcaivano/laravel-amp

Comment: "Is this something that should be brought to Stack Overflow's attention" Not sure what SO could be doing about it? It seems more or less unrelated, except that the code was also posted here.

Comment: I don't get it - why is this posted here? If the DMCA was against a GH repo, that isn't related to SO at all. (disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer, this is not legal advice, blah blah) The code is licensed under CC-By-SA 2.5-4.0. Attribution is required. If you build an entire repo around an answer without proper attribution, and a license change, that's technically a license violation. But as already mentioned, there's nothing SO can do about it. Contest the DMCA if you really disagree, but posting on meta won't do anything.

Comment: Also, from the language used in the DMCA notice, you can tell this is an individual and not a company. If SO pushed the takedown notice, it would probably be run through their lawyers, who would send a takedown notice with fancy lawyer language, not what actually was sent.

Comment: While I'm at it, I find it ironic that this shows up after [SE wrote a post on copy-pasta](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/20/good-coders-borrow-great-coders-steal/)

Answer (score 2):

In regards to your statement here:

> That is false, as code submitted to Stack Overflow is licensed under a Creative Commons license.

...there's some up-front print to the Creative Commons license which should be fairly obvious to any licensor, emphasis mine.

> Considerations for licensors: Our public licenses are intended for use **by those authorized** to give the public permission to use material in ways otherwise restricted by copyright and certain other rights.

So...just because *Stack Overflow* distributes its content under CC-By-SA 2.5-4.0, that doesn't mean that the *repository* is automatically covered by CC-By-SA **if the original poster doesn't have the authorization to redistribute it**.  That is to say, fundamentally, you can't put a new license on a work you don't control in the first place.

Which is *likely* why the answer was nuked from orbit.

On Anime & Manga, [we got involved with a brush with the DMCA](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4050/102) and have been living in a vacuum ever since that incident.  The CM who was going to give us a reply had this fall off of their radar, and I can't even ask for an update on it now.  Quite frankly, [from this response on what DMCA requests entail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317712/175248), if you want to contest it, ***you're*** going to have to send a DMCA counter notice, not Stack Overflow Inc.

Comment: Hi Makoto, I didn't say the repo would be covered. The takedown notice appears to be claiming the question on stackoverflow is copyrighted, and that's why the repo should be taken down. Also it's not my repo....

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to here when you say *"Which is likely why the answer was nuked from orbit"*. No posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707938/google-amp-with-laravel) were deleted due to DCMA takedown notices. Moderators don't handle those at all.

Comment: @Makoto it seems that, at least the post I reviewed, content was restored in A&M. Do you know how exactly did that pan out, wrt claims on non-media elements? Did Removeyourmedia faced any lawsuit for filling false claims that didn't consider fair use?

Comment: The answer wasn't nuked from orbit, it seems the link in the claim only points to the question instead of the specific answer.

Comment: All user provided content is provided automatically as CC by SA as per stackextange 
TOS https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing

Comment: @medic17:  No...if you *don't* have the ability to release the content as that license, it would still retain its original licensing conditions.  We've had tech employees request that source code be removed from the site because it contained corporate proprietary secrets.

Comment: @Makoto I meant code we write to make us of some proprietary code. If you write a proprietary API and give me access I can write code that uses it and post that here then it would be CC

Answer (score -12):

This is a legal matter between the repo owner and the claimant. It is generally best for everyone if outsiders don't interfere without one or both parties' invitation.

If you're the owner of the repository, you could attempt to reach out to the answerers through Stack Exchange, e.g. by commenting under any answer actually used in the repository. That could open up a dialogue and resolve the issue less messily than if you took the claim-counterclaim-lawsuit route.

Comment: I would caution a user against submitting a multiple iterations of the same comment against different answers.  The most likely scenario is those comments would be simply flagged.  Until the DMCA claim is against Stack Exchange there isn't anything the Stack Overflow community can do.  A DMCA claim against a Github repository doesn't have anything to do with Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SecurityHound good point. I suppose I should amend it to "each applicable answer", which in this case would narrow it down to 1 answer.

Comment: I will be more clear.  Do not submit a comment to the author’s of random answers.  If there is a problem flag the answer so a moderator can deal with it.  Even flagging for a moderator has its problems, realistically, it’s up to the copyright holder to deal with.  So unless that’s you disregard the advice contained within this answer.

Comment: @SecurityHound I'm not sure I follow; I'm suggesting that the owner of the repository get in touch with the copyright holder, and you seem to be claiming that getting in touch with the copyright holder is something the copyright holder should do. I trust you don't mean to imply that the copyright holder should hold a dialogue with themselves.

Comment: I am suggesting the copyright holder shouldn't submit comments to answers.  An answer that contains a link to a repository that is inaccessible is a problem the community should deal with.  If the copyright holder wishes to issue a DMCA claim they should go through that process (which does not involve submitting a comment).